# xsd: attribute points to element id

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an xml describing vertices on a directed graph:

```
<graph>
  <vertex id="a">
    <edge target="b"/>
  </vertex>
  <vertex id="b"/>
</graph>
```

Given the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="vertex">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="edge" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="edge">
    <xs:attribute name="target" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="graph">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="vertex" type="vertex" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="graph" type="graph"/>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I modify the `target` attribute so it's value can only be valid vertex id's?

so my initial example is a valid xml but:

```
<graph>
  <vertex id="a">
    <edge target="c"/>
  </vertex>
  <vertex id="b"/>
</graph>
```

is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a key/keyref pair.  Define them at the `graph` level, to enforce that the `vertex` IDs are unique:

```
<xs:element name="graph" type="graph">
  <xs:key name="vertexKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="vertex" />
    <xs:field xpath="@id" />
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref name="edgeRef" refer="vertexKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="vertex/edge" />
    <xs:field xpath="@target" />
  </xs:keyref>    
</xs:element>
```

Importantly, you also need to add a `type` to the `target` attribute of `edge`, as the types of the key and the reference must be compatible:

```
<xs:complexType name="edge">
  <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

(additionally the `edge` element under the `vertex` type is missing a `name`, but I presume this is a copy/paste mistake as the validator would have complained more loudly if your real schema were like that)

Comment: doesn't work for me. The solution does produce error if the vertex ids are not unique but both of the xml instances supplied in the question are validated against this schema. If it's a quick fix that you can edit then I'll revoke my downvote and upvote you

Comment: I though it might be a scope issue and moved the keyref definition to the graph element as well (and changed the selector accordingly). Now both xmls fail validation with the following error: Key 'edgeRef' with value 'b' not found for identity constraint of element 'graph'.

Comment: @eladidan got it - the referring attribute (`target`) needs a type declaration to allow it to match the vertex `id` (which is declared as `xs:string`).

Comment: This is outside the scope of my original question, but in my actual use-case, there are many types of edges, all deriving from an abstract `edge` type.  How can I apply this solution to my schema without having to specify each derived edge type explicitly in the selector (i.e. without something like: `xs:selector xpath="vertex/edgeA | vertex/edgeB | vertex/edgeC | ..."`)

Comment: @eladidan the subset of XPath that `selector` and `field` support is quite limited.  You could do `vertex/*` but I can't see how you could do anything finer-grained than that as you're not allowed to do predicates (with full XPath I'd suggest something like `vertex/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'edge')]` but that's not allowed here).

Comment: @eladidan If you control the format I suppose you could change the schema to group all the edges under a common parent and then use something like `vertex/edges/*`

Comment: Thanks, those are good ideas. I really want to do this without breaking the current xml structure but if that would not be possible I guess these solutions will suffice (the xml structure is due a big overhaul anyway so it might be a good opportunity to clean it up a bit).